# adjust image height in bootstrap carousel when mobile state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was able to get the bootstrap 4 carousel and images to from tablet to desktop but when the phone is in portrait view the image is stretch to tall. The height: 100vh; is positioning the image properly everywhere else but how can I override this in a portrait mobile state?

Demo page http://dninstalls.com/blankbootstrap/

CSS

```
    .carousel {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 81px);
    overflow: hidden;

}

.carousel,
.carousel-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 540px;
            min-height: auto;
            max-height: auto;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 575px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 100%;
            min-height: auto;
            max-height: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<header id="carouselHeader" class="page-header">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!--                    Carousel image 1 -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbbj%20kids.png" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 2 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20kids2.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 3 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20adult.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
                <!--                    Carousel image 4 -->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/mbjj%20comp.png" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the vh property and use max-heignt, min-height property and proper media Query ...

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

You need to use max-height and min-height property to `.carousel, .carousel-item img` this class. According to device Dimension the image ration should be changed... See the below link, Will get all the codes form here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/